# JSX multi line of html block did not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why within map it can't have multiple block of html?

```
{item.educations.map(item => 
    <p>Qualification: {item.title}</p>
    <p>Description: {item.description}</p>
)}
```

This worked

```
{item.educations.map(item => 
    <p>Qualification: {item.title}</p>
)}
```

This is my array of object:

```
"educations": [{
        "title": "Diploma",
        "description": "Design"
    },
{
        "title": "Degree",
        "description": "Programming"
    }]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can't `return` more than one `html` element, so if you want to `return` a multiple element, Wrap them in a `div` or by any other element, it will work, try this:

```
{item.educations.map(item =>{
    return( 
        <div>
           <p>Qualification: {item.title}</p>
           <p>Description: {item.description}</p>
        </div>
    )}
)}
```

or you can write it like this also:

```
{item.educations.map(item =>
     <p>Qualification: {item.title} <br/> Description: {item.description}</p>
)}
```

[From Doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html):

> Currently, in a component's render, you can only return one node; if
>   you have, say, a list of divs to return, you must wrap your components
>   within a div, span or any other component.
>
> Don't forget that JSX compiles into regular JS;

Answer (score 0):

With React v16.2.0, you can now use fragments using <> to wrap your components instead of using div tags.

```
{item.educations.map(item =>{
    return( 
        <>
           <p>Qualification: {item.title}</p>
           <p>Description: {item.description}</p>
        </>
    )}
)}
```

https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a code sample and not just a reference for your answer. We have guidelines on [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @JosephCho Okay, I have added a code example. The link you provided about how to write a good answer doesn't seem to include anything about including a code example. Maybe I just missed it.

Comment: With React v16.2.0, you can now use fragments using <> to wrap your elements (instead of components)